# Print odd numbered lines, starting with the first line

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to write a bash script than prints only odd lines of file, including the first line without used `sed` or `awk`, also without &&, || and ;

Comment: The requirements seem awfully arbitrary. What is the point? Is this a homework? The question (like any question) should show reasonable research effort. What is your attempt so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Voted to close as too broad - it's not clear what was attempted here, and where the problem that the asker has lie. As such, a good answer would have to explain far too much

Comment: When asking questions about text processing, please be sure to always include example input along with the desired output. Also, please show what you tried and where you faced difficulties, so that contributors trying to help don't propose solutions you already know won't work.

Answer (score 3):

With `perl`:

```
$ seq 10 | perl -ne 'print if $.%2'
1
3
5
7
9
```

If the input doesn't contain TAB characters, you can also do:

```
$ seq 10 | paste - - | cut -f1
1
3
5
7
9
```

With GNU `grep`:

```
$ seq 10 | grep -n '^' | LC_ALL=C grep -Po '^\d*[13579]:\K.*'
1
3
5
7
9
```

In any case, [you shouldn't use a shell loop to process text](/q/169716). If that's what your teacher expects with those weird requirements, get another teacher as they'd be teaching you bad practice. A shell's role is before all to run other commands. And as a shell scripter, you want to pick the best command for the job (here `perl`, `sed` or `awk`) or a set of commands that collaborate together as intended by the Unix authors when they invented those pipelines some 50 years ago.

Comment: This `perl` solution is quite elegant, but it does not satisfy the requirements. From the question: "I want to write a bash script". The `perl` command is standalone, it's not a bash script. Your other solutions use `|`, so they really require a shell like bash, this makes them little closer to "bash scripts". One can wrap `perl` in a bash script though. It would make the answer better (the requirement would be met) and worse at the same time (objectively such wrapping is not the Right Thing).

Comment: The `#bash@irc.libera.chat` (previously on `freenode`) team that is owning shellcheck, bash-hackers, bashFAQ, woodledge and so on, says that `seq(1) is nonstandard, inefficient and useless` Dixit `greybot`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, that's shell code that invokes `perl`. Also works in the  bash shell. A shell is a tool to run commands.

Comment: @GillesQuénot, `seq`  here is not part of the answer,  it's a tool used to  provide sample data to demonstrate the answer.

Comment: So… every command is a bash script. Right? A custom binary executable that solves the OP's problem out of the box is a bash script, because one can invoke it from bash. Right?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, yes, `mytool arg` is code in the shell syntax. That executes `/path/to/mytool` with `mytool`, and `arg` as arguments in a child process and waits for its termination. A roughly equivalent perl script would be `system("mytool", "arg");`

Comment: @GillesQuénot, note that the `printf '%s\n' {1..n}` zshism (since copied by many other shells) you used in your answer is less efficient than `seq n`  for large values of `n` (where efficiency matters), as it implies storing the whole list of numbers (as strings converted from numbers likely through some sprintf() call internally)  in memory several times. Compare `time bash -c 'seq 10000000' > /dev/null` with `time bash -c 'printf "%s\n" {1..10000000}' > /dev/null` for instance.

Comment: Good to know, thanks

Comment: OK, I get your point. Still, when one explicitly requests a bash script, a solution that uses bash only to invoke a tool that uses another language to do all the job single-handedly is not necessarily what he or she means. I suspect this is the reason `awk` and `sed` are explicitly forbidden. The question is *probably* a homework-like task and the point *probably* is to use bash for something more than invoking a single executable. IMO if calling the `perl` solution "bash script" meets the requirements, so would a solution using `gawk`. `gawk` is not forbidden, `awk` is; why not use `gawk`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, but IMO, [giving a solution using a shell loop](/q/169716) to process text, even one that only  uses builtin commands of one particular shell implementation would be a disservice to the  OP. If that's what their teacher want, they should get another teacher.

Comment: And this is what earned you a +1 from me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do 
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
    IFS= read -r _
done <"file"
```

Trying with `seq`:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do 
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
    IFS= read -r _
done < <(seq 10)
1
3
5
7
9
```

Comment: mind the arbitrary no semicolons rules.

Comment: @MarcusMüller could you expand on this rule?

Comment: @aviro, the OP said *no ;*. See edit.